# Unable to access scope using fat arrow

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, scope, coffeescript

I'm probably missing something very basic regarding scoping.

Can anyone please explain what is going on and how to properly access the object `ngModelController` from the outer scope within `scope.$watch`?

Here's an example:

```
myDirModule = angular.module("myDir", []) 
.directive "myDir", ($compile) -> 
restrict: "A"
require: "ngModel" 
scope:  
  myParam: "=ngModel" 
compile: (element, attrs) -> 

  // ... more code here ...

  post: (scope, element, attrs, ngModelController) -> 

    // ... more code here ...

    // ngModelController defined here :D

    scope.$watch 'myParam', (newValue, oldValue) =>
      // ngModelController NOT defined here :(
```

Answer (score 0):

Return the postlink function directly to the compile function:

```
myDirModule = angular.module("myDir", []) 
.directive "myDir", ($compile) -> 
restrict: "A"
require: "ngModel" 
scope:  
  myParam: "=ngModel" 
compile: (element, attrs) -> 
  # more code here
  # return postlink function directly
  (scope, element, attrs, ngModelController) ->
    console.log(ngModelContoller)
```

Or return the pre and post functions as a hash

```
myDirModule = angular.module("myDir", []) 
.directive "myDir", ($compile) -> 
restrict: "A"
require: "ngModel" 
scope:  
  myParam: "=ngModel" 
compile: (element, attrs) -> 
  # more code goes here
  # return pre and post as a hash
  pre: (scope, element, attrs, ngModelController) ->
    console.log(ngModelController)
  post: (scope, element, attrs, ngModelController) ->
    console.log(ngModelContoller)
```

Also be sure to use `->`, not `=>`